# Rank Nullity theorem for R2 to R3

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

The rank nullity theorem in abstract algebra says that the rank of a linear transformation (i.e, the number of dimensions space is squished to) + its nullity (The number of dimensions that get squished) gives the dimension of the original vector space. How can I use the same intuition to explain a transformation T:R^2--->R^3? Can the nullity be allowed to be negative?

Comment: It is a theorem, not an "intuition". What do you mean by "explain a transformation"? The nullity is always $\ge0.$ Depending on which $T:k^2\to k^3$ you consider, the theorem can only take one of the following forms: $2+0=2,$ $1+1=2,$ $0+2=2.$

Comment: I think you just convinced yourself that such a $T$ cannot be surjective.

Comment: I had not considered that the image will be a subspace of R3. Thank you, I got it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand you are referring to the following theorem:

Let $L : V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation, with $V$ a finite-dimensional vector space. Then:
$$\dim V = \dim (\ker( L)) + \dim (L(V ))$$
where the dimension of the image $L(V)$, a subspace of $W$, is the rank of $L$ and the dimension of the kernel $\ker(L)$, a subspace of $V$, is the nullity of $L$.

So neither of this two numbers can be negative since they are dimensions of subspaces. A linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is absolutly possible since the image $T(\mathbb{R}^2)$ can be a $0$, $1$ or $2$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so the nullity can be also $0$, $1$ or $2$.

Comment: Understood, thank you.

Comment: My pleasure, please mark my answer correct so the post is closed :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a theorem, not an "intuition".

What do you mean by "explain a transformation"?

The nullity is always $≥0.$

Depending on which $T:\Bbb R^2→\Bbb R^3$ you consider, the theorem can only take one of the following forms:
$$2+0=2,\quad 1+1=2,\quad 0+2=2.$$